# bash select command

Tags: linux, bash, select

I'm trying to run a script that uses the select command and I get error below.  I'm running the most recent version of ubuntu.  Why does it say the commands are not found?

```
#!/bin/bash
# Scriptname: runit
PS3= "Select a program to execute: "
select program in 'ls -F' pwd date cal exit
do
  $program
done
```

### This is the output:

```
runit.sh: 3: Select a program to execute: : not found
runit.sh: 4: select: not found
runit.sh: 5: Syntax error: "do" unexpected
```

Answer (score 1):

Delete the space after the equal sign:

```
PS3= "Select a program to execute: "
    ^
```

Comment: Thanks, but now I'm getting:  `runit.sh: 4: select: not found
runit.sh: 5: Syntax error: "do" unexpected`  Could this be because of what version of bash I have?  It says I have `GNU bash, version 4.2.8(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)`

Comment: @sq1020 It works fine on my laptop with `PS3="Select a program to execute: "` and `GNU bash, version 4.2.10(2)-release (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu)`

Comment: @sq1020: make sure that there is no typo or uppercase in the word `select`